# Migrating from AppEngine files to cloudstorage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

The files API has an unannounced downtime (ApiTemporaryUnavailableError) yesterday, that lasted for several hours.

We are now  thinking about replacing the (now deprecated) files API with cloudstorage (GCS), but still continue to use the blobstore API for other operations (like file uploads or downloads). We would also keep existing files written with the files API in blobstore.

The main problem seems to be, that our application is using the BlobInfo (to determine mime types, file names, list blobs) later on. But the documentation says, that files written on GCS and inserted via blobstore.create_gs_key into the blobstore don't have a BlobInfo.

What are possible solutions?

- Write a storage arbiter (that either uses BlobInfo or GCS meta data)
- Keep an own BlobInfo data table in addition to google table
- Convert the complete code base away from blobstore to GCS (and migrate existing blobs into GCS)
- Forget about AppEngine and run our standalone application (see below) on Compute Engine or EC2
- ???

Note: We do also have a standalone version of our application (that runs locally), that uses a private implementation of the parts of the AppEngine API (we don't use dev server,) that is used by our application. So every piece of code  needs also a local implementation.

Comment: it's definitely not an answer, but I think it's worth pointing out that the files API is back up. Not meaning it won't go back down, but your old code should work for a little while :)

Comment: If you decide to keep using AppEngine, the future proof solution is to refactor the code to GCS and migrate existing blobs to GCS (e.g. a simple mapreduce which will iterate over all entities, reads blobs and writes them to GCS).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gist about using GCS. Have a look here: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133
It shows how to install and use a GCS app in DEV and deployed.

Comment: I Lready understood how to write to GCS. My problem is, that our application uses the BlobInfo Do you get a BlobInfo for the GCS files?

Comment: GCS has a function interface and not a BlobInfo like class. But you can write your own BlobInfo class which uses these functions for the default bucket. I do not expect great difficulties for the ones you mention: mime types, file names and list blob. Is this what you mean with stoarage arbiter?

Comment: We currently have data in the blobstore (referenced in other part if the database via blobkey). So either we move them into GCS ;and update the references) or we need code which handles blobstore and GCS (thats what I meant with arbiter)